# go to next array on click php ( ajax ? )

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I would like to affect php when i'm clicking button :
(I know the difference between client-side & server-side. But I'm pretty sure to have already seen something similar.)

I have this array :

```
    $test_id = [
        1 => '15124'
        2 => '26845'
        3 => '57845'
        ....
    ];

echo current($test_id);

echo '<input type="submit" name="next" value="next">';
```

I would like each time i'm clicking on button to echo the next titlte_id, in order of id, for example.

I know I'll have to do something with ajax or maybe with a form post ?

Comment: There is not enough code + explanation in here to have any clue what you are trying to do

Comment: Re your (now deleted) question. Angular will work fine with PHP/MySQL. Do you have any error messages? Have you traced Angular's AJAX operations to see if they fire, and what they do? (I expect you were being downvoted because it was not possible to determine the problem from the brief description).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the data through the query string.

```
<?php
    $index = intval($_GET['index']);
    if (!index) {
      $index = 1;
    }
?>
<a href="sameScript.php?index=<?php echo $index + 1; ?>">Next</a>
```

You'll probably want smarter error checking than that though.

Comment: Thank you, and there is a way if "id" have random numbers ?

Comment: Then you'll need some logic on the server to determine which one is "next" that is more complicated than just incrementing the value.

Answer (score 0):

try something like that with php but you have to carry clicked value($clickedValue) every time

```
$test_id = array('15124','26845','57845');

$current = array_search($clickedValue, $test_id);
$prevID = $test_id[$current-1];
$nextID = $test_id[$current+1];
```